Does the RFC9110 field-content grammar imply content can not be 2 characters wide?
When reading the field-content grammar specified in RFC9110
field-content = field-vchar [ 1*( SP / HTAB / field-vchar ) field-vchar ]

I came to the conclusion that this grammar does allow the field content to be 1 or >= 3 characters wide. This implies it can not be 2 characters wide.
Sure the field-value can be of any character width, so it does not have an effect on the actual value.
field-value = *field-content

Is this observation even correct? If so, what's the reason for the grammar to be like that?
I was taking a look at the older specification in RFC7230, which defines the rule like
field-content = field-vchar [ 1*( SP / HTAB ) field-vchar ]

This is how I would naively expect it to be.
Edit: I'm assuming this was done to prevent trailing white spaces.
Edit: Looks like it's meant for the case a field value of "a b c" needs to be parsed. The legacy grammar can only match "a b".
